# How do i make an unordered list show and hide when a different div (menu i created) is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(".menu").click(function () {
   if ('.pagelinks').style.display = 'none';
   {
      $('.pagelinks').style.display = 'block';
   }
   else
   {
      $('.pagelinks').style.display = 'none';
   }
})
```

```css
html,body
{
    margin:0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;

}

body
{
    background: url(best8.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
}

header
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    height: 85px;
    position: fixed;
}

.heading1
{
    
    color:white;
    position: relative;
    align-content: center;
    margin: 3em ;
    top: 100px;
    left: 675px;
}


.logo img
{
    left: 0;
    filter: brightness 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

.menu 
{
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 75%;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 11px;
}

.nav div
{
    height: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 4px 0;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav
{
    width: 30px;
    display: block;
    margin: 1em 0 0 
}

.one
{
    width: 30px;
}

.two
{
    width: 20px;
}

.three
{
    width: 25px;
}

.nav:hover div 
{
    width: 30px; 
}

.pagelinks
{
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 49%;
    position: fixed;
    top: -10px;
    display: none;
    
    
}

.pagelinks ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.pagelinks ul li
{
    float: left;
    padding:30px;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 0.3;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 40px;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.pagelinks ul li:hover
{
    color: green;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

.logo img:hover
{
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Goesta Calculators</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <script src="https://use.typekit.net/axs3axn.js"></script>
    
    <script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true});}catch(e){}</script>
    
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
    
<body>
  <header>
      <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <a href="" class="logo"> <img src="NewLogo.PNG" ></a>
        <div class="menu">
           <a href="" class="nav">
           <div class="one"></div>
           <div class="two"></div>
           <div class="three"></div>  
        </a>
           </div>
           <nav class="pagelinks">
               <ul>
                   <a href="" class="about"> <li>About</li></a>
                   <a href="" class="contact"><li>Contact</li></a>
                   <a href="" class="calculators"><li>Calculators</li></a>
               </ul>
           </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
    </header>
     <div class="heading1">
      <h1>Estimate. Plan your future.</h1>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to make an unordered list show/hide when another `div` with `.menu` class, is clicked. I've tried several different ways in javascript from research online but nothing is working. I also want it to transition slowly and smoothly. When I click the menu (I'm assuming because its a link) the page seems to refresh.

Comment: If you have a question please formulate it according to the guidelines.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

please send your code ...

Comment: It is saying my code isn't indented correctly and I cant figure it out. The last question i posted i didn't have a problem and even updated the code once. can i add it in a comment i guess?

Comment: Add your code to your question (not in a comment).

Comment: Make sure that when you're adding code to your question you either add a code block by clicking the button for it in the toolbar or wrapping your code in three backticks or choose to create a snippet by clicking the button on the toolbar and pasting your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code in the relevant sections.

Comment: @Mac I posted an answer. Check if it solved your problem. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your condition syntax is very wrong.

```
if ('.pagelinks').style.display = 'none';
```

Don't put semicolon in there. And wrap your condition with open and close parenthesis.

Second, use `.css()` if you want to modify your css.

Here's the working version of your jQuery

```
$(".menu").click(function () {
   if ($('.pagelinks').css("display") == 'none')
   {
      $('.pagelinks').css("display", "block");
   }
   else
   {
      $('.pagelinks').css("display", "none");
   }
})
```

Also, don't use anchor tag on your nav if it is only a trigger. Use `<div>` instead.
Like this

```
<div class="nav">
   <div class="one"></div>
   <div class="two"></div>
   <div class="three"></div>  
</div>
```

And if you have problem with the cursor not transforming into a hand, just have this in your css

```
.nav:hover
{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Working Sandbox of your code [HERE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WWgNGE?editors=1111)

Comment: I see that it works in Sandbox, but it's not working in my text editor. did i link js and jquery correctly in the head? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I figured out how to do it. I don't know if I did it the right way to be honest but it works and its clean. I updated the Script tag in the head to include the type, and then in the body at the end of the header I wrote a script tag again referencing the js file. Thanks for your help!

Comment: yeah. based on my experience, js script references are always located at the lowest part of your body tag. Also, please mark this as an answer if solved your problem so others who are experiencing the same will know that this is the solution. Thanks